# How to move an opaque value like a hot potato from one Enum constructor to the next to the next?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, linear-types

I'd like to make the following `Padded` type into an iterator transformer:

```
enum Step<T> {
    Before(T),
    During(T),
    After
}

struct Padded<T> {
    step: Step<T>
}
```

(Note that in my real code, there's stuff other than just `Step` inside `Padded`, hence the extra layer of indirection from `struct` to `enum`.)

The idea is that in each iteration, we always change our `Step` and so it should be kosher to move the `T` stored in it into the next `Step`'s constructor. However, I can't get it to work.

Straightforward version:

```
impl<T: Iterator> Iterator for Padded<T> {
    type Item = Option<T::Item>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match &self.step {
            Step::Before(start) => {
                self.step = Step::During(*start);
                Some(None)
            },
            Step::During(ref mut iter) => {
                match iter.next() {
                    Some(x) => { self.step = Step::During(*iter); Some(Some(x)) },
                    None => { self.step = Step::After; Some(None) },
                }
            },
            Step::After => {
                None
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*start` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lcd.rs:39:42
   |
39 |                 self.step = Step::During(*start);
   |                                          ^^^^^^ move occurs because `*start` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a `&` reference as mutable
  --> src/lcd.rs:42:26
   |
42 |             Step::During(ref mut iter) => {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*iter` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lcd.rs:44:59
   |
44 |                     Some(x) => { self.step = Step::During(*iter); Some(Some(x)) },
   |                                                           ^^^^^ move occurs because `*iter` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I tried making it a bit more obvious that `self.step` is not long for this world anyway, by changing the third branch to:

```
            Step::After => {
                self.step = Step::After;
                None
            }
```

but that doesn't change anything.

Then I thought I'd spell it out even more explicitly what is going on here:

```
impl<T: Iterator> Padded<T> {
    fn next_self_and_item(self) -> (Self, Option<Option<T::Item>>) {
        match self.step {
            Step::Before(start) => {
                (Padded{ step: Step::During(start) }, Some(None))
            },
            Step::During(mut iter) => {
                match iter.next() {
                    Some(x) => (Padded{ step: Step::During(iter) }, Some(Some(x))),
                    None => (Padded{ step: Step::After }, Some(None)),
                }
            },
            Step::After => {
                (Padded{ step: Step::After }, None)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This one does pass the borrow checker, but can't be used to implement `Iterator::next`:

```
impl<T: Iterator> Iterator for Padded<T> {
    type Item = Option<T::Item>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let (new_self, item) = self.next_self_and_item();
        *self = new_self;
        item
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*self` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lcd.rs:79:32
   |
79 |         let (new_self, item) = self.next_self_and_item();
   |                                ^^^^ -------------------- `*self` moved due to this method call
   |                                |
   |                                move occurs because `*self` has type `Padded<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
note: `Padded::<T>::next_self_and_item` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `*self`
  --> src/lcd.rs:57:27
   |
57 |     fn next_self_and_item(self) -> (Self, Option<Option<T::Item>>) {
   |                           ^^^^
```

So what can I do? Also, am I right in thinking that at least morally, what I'm trying to do should be fine, since `self` is a mutable reference (so I should be able to do whatever I want to `self.step`), and in all branches the `T` inside `self.step` is merely moved around?

Comment: *" I should be able to do whatever I want to `self.step`"* – wrong, a mutable reference still always has to point to a value valid for that type, that's why you can't move `step`. Consider what happens when between moving and replacing it there is a `panic!`, then `self.step` would be uninitialized (still pointing to the old data) and both the caller and the function itself would try to free it.

Comment: I reopened this question because it seemed a clear candidate for `std::mem::replace()`, unlike the duplicate where it's not possible because the enum has no trivially constructible variant. While some of the answers in the other question do mention `replace()`, they only do it in passing, since it doesn't apply to that question. The answer by the OP there even advocates replacing with `mem::uninitialized()`, which is just UB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it is **not** allowed to move a non-`Copy` value out of a reference without caring what remains there. This is because a Rust reference is owned by someone else and is expected to always refer to valid data. If the compiler allowed such extraction, then a panic (or just an early return) would leave the owner with a destructed value, leading to a crash or worse.

However, if you can supply a valid alternative value, [`std::mem::replace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) allows you to extract the value from the reference while leaving the specified replacement in its place. Since your `Step` enum has a variant that doesn't contain a `T`, you can easily retrieve your "hot potato" by (temporarily) replacing `self.step` with `Step::After`:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    // take ownership of self.step by replacing it with Step::After
    match std::mem::replace(&mut self.step, Step::After) {
        Step::Before(start) => {
            self.step = Step::During(start);
            Some(None)
        }
        Step::During(mut iter) => match iter.next() {
            Some(x) => {
                self.step = Step::During(iter);
                Some(Some(x))
            }
            None => Some(None), // we've already changed it to Step::After
        },
        Step::After => None,
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=afffb42d42325c76d84e82090f42082b)

`std::mem::replace()` is allowed to move value out of a mut reference because it guarantees that no arbitrary code (which could panic) runs before the new value is swapped in.